# Appending dynamic field to object

Tags: javascript

I'm getting field name using:

```
var getColumnName = params.colDef.field;
```

I want to make `params.data` to have field which is stored in `getColumnName` and set the value `null` to make it accessible like:

```
params.data.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array notation instead of object notation:

```
if (!params.data) params.data = {};
params.data[getColumnName] = null;
```

Comment: Hi, @Alejandro De Cicco, it worked well brother. Thanks for your quick response.Though I can't upvote. I will accept this answer.